# Copying files using SCP in maven

Tags: maven, scp

http://maksim.sorokin.dk/it/2010/08/26/copy-files-with-scp-using-maven/

Followed the above article to copy files from a Windows machine into a EC2 Windows 2008 machine, it throws the following exception.

```
[scp] Connecting to ec2-51-12-238-250.compute-1.amazonaws.com:22
[scp] Caught exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out error
```

I get the above exception even when the machine is UP and running, what could be wrong here?

Comment: Does the remote machine have an ssh server running?

Comment: not sure how should I check in the Win 2008 machine

Comment: Have you tried to do a ssh connection via command line or putty ? What kind of machine is the target machine?

Comment: Target machine is a Win 2008 machine (EC2 instance)

Comment: Hm. Win machines usually don't have ssh daemon running except you've installed cygwin etc. on it. Furthermore have you checked firewall settings on the machine (port 22 ?)  Apart from that have you checked to manually ssh on the machine? (I assume you don't?)